# Hard disk space usage goes from 96% to 100% one minute after restart

Tags: macos, ssd, disk-space, resources

I have a mid 2014 MacBook Pro 13" (MacBookPro11,1) with 128 GB SSD. I have a lot of applications that I use that won't work on a external hard drive, so I always have issues with space. But going from 5 GB to 0 in a minute after restart? I had a look at the memory, and I'm only using 3 GB of 8 GB. This started immediately after last update to OS X Yosemite. 10.10.5.

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size   Used  Avail Capacity  iused   ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1     112Gi  107Gi  5.1Gi    96% 27985010 1338252   95%   /
devfs          182Ki  182Ki    0Bi   100%      630       0  100%   /dev
map -hosts       0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%        0       0  100%   /net
map auto_home    0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%        0       0  100%   /home

# username at my-mac.local in ~ [16:14:51]
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size   Used  Avail Capacity  iused  ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1     112Gi  108Gi  3.6Gi    97% 28384440 938822   97%   /
devfs          182Ki  182Ki    0Bi   100%      630      0  100%   /dev
map -hosts       0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%        0      0  100%   /net
map auto_home    0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%        0      0  100%   /home

# username at my-mac.local in ~ [16:15:21]
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size   Used  Avail Capacity  iused  ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1     112Gi  111Gi  795Mi   100% 29119752 203510   99%   /
devfs          182Ki  182Ki    0Bi   100%      630      0  100%   /dev
map -hosts       0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%        0      0  100%   /net
map auto_home    0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%        0      0  100%   /home
```

I get alerts that disk space limit reached.

After restarting the Mac it happens again.

Comment: The usual view is you need at least %% space free - in this case I would temporarily remove some apps/data from the SSD and then see what happens - then you can run a disk viewer like OmniDiskSweeper to see what takes up space

Comment: Thank you. OmniDiskSweeper, helped me remove some stuff. I cannot wait to the internal hard drives for this are on sale. Still nothing over a year later, and will probably be $1,000 for 1TB. Uggghhh.

Answer (score 2):

Next time it happens, try:

```
sudo find / -mmin -5 2>/dev/null
```

This will list all directories & files, created or modified within the last 5 minutes.